# C# - Parse data type that's stored in a string

Tags: c#

Is it possible to parse a string onto a data type that's stored in a string variable?
Example:

```
var dataType = "Int32";
var value = "123";
dynamic value = dataType.parse(value);
```

Comment: There's this amazing thing called "reflection" but it's mad science. What's your use case? I wonder if this might be an XY problem.

Comment: @madreflection I'm already using reflection to retrieve the properties of the class so I'm not against using it in this case. I have a database table that stores multiple answers to a form and their values in the database are in nvarchar. There's a column along side that indicates which data type to be used once it goes through the server.

Comment: Thank you for this, however I can't add packages in this project per the team's standard. Is there a way to do this besides using that?

Comment: That's an unfortunate restriction. But if I was able to do it, you should be able to do something similar yourself. You have the type. Find the "Parse" method and call it.

Comment: @madreflection, appropriate username :D

Comment: `int.Parse(string)`, `long.Parse(string)`, `DateTime.Parse(string)`...

Comment: But why are you storing data in a database in `nvarchar` store it in the correct column type. If you don't know then you are much better off having a few columns of different types and only one is allowed (by check constraint) to contain a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

1. Convert `dataType` to a `Type` by using [`Type.GetType(dataType)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetType_System_String_). Keep in mind that you may need to use the full assembly-qualified name, for instance, `"Int32"` may not be enough and you may need to use `"System.Int32"`.
2. Once you have the `Type`, use [`Convert.ChangeType(value, type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-5.0) (where `type` is the `Type` variable) to convert the value to the appropiate type. `Convert.ChangeType` returns an `object` so you are going to have to cast it unless you are fine with using `dynamic`.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're (presumably) only dealing with a handful of primitive types, a `switch` statement would be faster than reflection:

```
dynamic value
switch dataType {
case "Int32":        
    value = Int32.Parse(text);
case "Int64":        
    value = Int64.Parse(text);
case "DateTime":        
    value = Int32.Parse(text);
...
}
```

But this begs more questions - if you don't know the type at compile-time, how are you going to *do* anything with it? If you use a dynamic variable, then all of your code that uses that variable will be dynamic and bound at run-time as well. So if you don't *need* to parse the data, why not just leave it as strings?

In other words, in my experience, using reflection or dynamic to allow for different data types stored as strings only gets you so far. Whenever you go to actually *use* the data (in formulas, for example), you end up with either a bunch of reflection or switches like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the type name (as a string) is fully qualified.  In your case, you want to be looking at `System.Int32` (note we've included the namespace).  So, to replicate your code above (Drop this in LINQPad):

```
string typeName = "System.Int32";
Type concreteType = Type.GetType(typeName);
object concreteInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(concreteType);
concreteInstance.Dump();
```

This will output `0` as we created an integer.  However, we can avoid the above if we register converters for specific types (in this case, by string):

```
void Main()
{
    object value = Set("System.Int32", "4");
    value.Dump();
}

Dictionary<string, Func<string, object>> converters = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, object>>()
{
    ["System.Int32"] = o => int.Parse(o)
};

object Set(string typeName, string value)
{
    if(converters.TryGetValue(typeName, out Func<string, object> converter))
        return converter(value);
        
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to call `Parse`. You're missing half the question there (the important part).

Comment: @madreflection, I was hoping to show that this is how you can create the type dynamically from a string.  I agree, the get/set is a bit more involved and probably needs to be a dictionary of types/strings to converters, but that's a bit beyond the scope of the question...

Comment: The parsing is how they need to create the type. They have the value as a string in a database.

Comment: @madreflection Added a basic example.